# A uniformly convergent sequence of real valued functions need not to be term by term Integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

We know that if $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a  sequence of real valued functions converging uniformly to a function $f$ in a bounded interval $[a, b]$, then sequence is term by term integrable, i. e.,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_a^bf_n(x)dx= \int_a^b\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)dx= \int_a^bf(x)dx$$

I am looking for the case when interval is unbound. I knew that result is not true for unbounded interval. But, I am anable to find/construct a counter example. Suggest me how can I find an example to disprove this result in unbounded intervals.

Comment: Try $f_n$ to be constants.

Comment: On this site "integrable" has many possible meanings.  You likely mean for $\int_a^b f_n(x)\,dx$ that each $f_n$ is Riemann integrable.  To be precise then you would say that $\int_a^\infty f_n(x)\,dx$ is interpreted in the *improper Riemann sense* which requires that each $f_n$ is Riemann integrable on all compact intervals in $[a,\infty)$.   The simplest counterexample might be $f_n(x)=\frac1n$ for $0\leq x \leq n$ and $f_n(x)=0$ for $n<x<\infty$.  But find a more dramatic example, even find a sequence of continuous functions.

Comment: I failed to notice B. S. Thompson's comment before giving a similar (but continuous) counterexample in the answers--darn.

Comment: @MAPelto  Continuous is good.  Otherwise one might think that some additional hypothesis would rescue this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What you *need* to know ...vs... What you  *want* to know.**

A simple counterexample shoots down a possible conjecture but does not do much to instruct you about the topic itself, especially one as important as this one.

So ...

**Situation for the Riemann integral with uniform convergence:**

1. *[Uniform convergence]*  Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of Riemann integrable functions on an interval $[a,b]$  such that  $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $[a,b]$.  Then (as you say)
   (i)  $f$ is also Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, and (ii) the limit identity holds:
   $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_a^bf_n(x)\,dx = \int_a^b \lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)\,dx =\int_a^bf(x)\,dx .\tag{1}$$

**Situation for the Riemann integral with  pointwise convergence:**

2. *[Pointwise convergence]*  Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of Riemann integrable functions on an interval $[a,b]$  such that  $f_n\to f$ pointwise [i.e., not uniformly] on $[a,b]$.  Then  (i)  $f$  *might not be bounded* and so it is not Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, and (ii) even if $f$ is bounded *it still might not be Riemann integrable* so you cannot claim the limit (1).
3. *[Arzelà-Osgood Bounded Convergence Theorem]*   Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of Riemann integrable functions on an interval $[a,b]$  such that  $f_n\to f$ pointwise [i.e., not uniformly] on $[a,b]$. Suppose that  $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly bounded (i.e., there is a number $M$ so that $|f_n(x)|\leq M$ for all $n$ and all $x$.
   Then
   (i)  $f$ must  be bounded but it might not be Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$, and
   (ii)  if, however,  $f$ is   Riemann integrable, then
   $$ \int_a^bf_n(x)\,dx \to \int_a^b f(x)\,dx.$$

**The unfortunate situation for the improper Riemann integral even with uniform convergence:**

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of functions on an interval $[0,\infty)$  such that  $f_n\to f$ uniformly on   $[0,\infty)$.  Suppose that each integral $\int_0^\infty f_n(x)\,dx$ exists in the improper Riemann sense.

Then we know for sure (from the first part) that

(i)  The function $f$ must be Riemann integrable on each bounded interval $[0,T]\subset [0,\infty)$.

(ii)  For each bounded interval $[0,T]\subset [0,\infty)$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^T f_n(x)\,dx = \int_0^T \lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)\,dx = \int_0^T  f(x)\,dx .\tag{2}$$

But we do not know if
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^\infty f_n(x)\,dx
=  \int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx .\tag{3}$$
because that is the same as swapping a double limit:
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^\infty f_n(x)\,dx
= \lim_{n\to \infty} \lim_{T\to \infty}\int_0^T f_n(x)\,dx= \lim_{T\to \infty} \int_0^T \lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)\,dx = \int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx .$$

***WARNING*: Never, ever swap two limits $\lim_A\lim_B = \lim_B\lim_A$ without serious thinking. In this case there are three limits, since the integration itself is defined as  limit.**

So the first step in understanding this is to search for counterexamples:

> **Problem.**  In each of the three cases below find an example of a  uniformly convergent sequence   $\{f_n\}$  of functions on an interval
> $[0,\infty)$  such that  $f_n\to f$ uniformly on   $[0,\infty)$ and
> each integral $\int_0^\infty f_n(x)\,dx$ exists in the improper
> Riemann sense but where
>
> Part (a): The integral $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx $ does not exist in the
> improper Riemann sense.
>
> Part  (b):  The limit $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^\infty f_n(x)\,dx$
> does not exist.
>
> Part (c):  The integral $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx $ does  exist in the
> improper Riemann sense and the limit $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^\infty
>   f_n(x)\,dx$  also exists but the two are not equal.

In the comments is the example $f_n(x)= \frac1n$ for $0\leq x \leq n$ and $f_n(x)=0$ for $n<x\leq \infty$.  This sequence converges uniformly to the zero function but
$\int_0^\infty f_n(x)\,dx = 1$ does not converge to zero.  This answers question (c) and you have left for your amusement questions (a) and (b).

Answer (score 1):

For $n=1,2, \ldots $, define $f_n:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$f_n(x):= \frac{1}{n}\displaystyle{\mathbf 1}_{[0,n]}(x)+\frac{1}{2}\left(  \frac{3}{n}-\frac{x}{n^2}\right)\displaystyle{\mathbf1}_{(n,3n)}(x) \,,$$
where $\mathbf{1}_S$ (for $S\subseteq \mathbb{R }$) is the characteristic function
$$\mathbf 1_S (x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{ if } x \in S \\
0 &  \text{ if } x \notin S
\end{cases}$$

Consider the sequence  $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$. Notice $f_n \to 0$ uniformly as we have $$\sup_{x \in [0,\infty)} |f_n(x)|=\frac{1}{n} \quad (n=1,2,\ldots).$$

However notice that for $n=1,2,\ldots$, we have
$$\int_0^\infty f_n(x)\,dx = 2. $$

We may combine our observations to see that we apparently have
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^\infty f_n(x)\,dx
= 2 \neq 0= \int_0^\infty \lim_{n\to \infty} f_n(x)\,dx .
$$

---

By linearity, the sequence given by the equation $\{2g_n\}_{n=1}^\infty:=\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ would be an example of a sequence that converges uniformly to $0$ but the limit of the integrals equals $1$.